# Get value closest to text outside tags

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I know the title is terrible, but I don't know even how to express what I want. This is the code:

```
<div class="card card-list">
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="10" class="card-list-item ">
<img src="/Images/ranked/a.png" style="width:25px;">
Ranked Duel 1v1
<span class="badge">874</span>
</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="11" class="card-list-item ">
<img src="/Images/ranked/b.png" style="width:25px;">
Ranked Doubles 2v2
<span class="badge">1188</span>
</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="12" class="card-list-item ">
<img src="/Images/ranked/c.png" style="width:25px;">
Ranked Solo Standard 3v3
<span class="badge">1047</span>
</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="13" class="card-list-item ">
<img src="/Images/ranked/d.png" style="width:25px;">
Ranked Standard 3v3
<span class="badge">1417</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Is there any way with xpath for extracting the class value "badge" from a determined untagged text? For example, I want to extract 'badge' value from "Ranked Standard 3v3" text (1417).
Or, if I issue xpath for "Ranked Doubles 2v2", it should return 'badge' value 1188.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to get appropriate value for "Ranked Standard 3v3"

```
//a[contains(., "Ranked Standard 3v3")]/span/text()
```

or

```
//text()[normalize-space()="Ranked Standard 3v3"]/following-sibling::span/text()
```